# Docker container is restarting

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and I encounter this issue. The efo_db seems to restart again and again. I do not know what is the error. [image]

[image]

[image]
Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Add the Dockerfile please

Comment: added @demouser123

Comment: Could you provide a full log of mysql container using `docker logs efo_db`? The screenshot does not contain the whole output.

Comment: You seem to have attached three image files to the question.  Does the process dump these image files directly to the console, or does it produce text-format logs?  Can you include any relevant application code or configuration files (as text, not images; directly in the question, not behind links) that demonstrate how to reproduce the issue?